# Metacity Debian

Tags: debian

Необходимо установить и настроить metacity на Debian

после установки metacity и удаления compiz и openbox

```
sudo apt-get install metacity
sudo apt-get remove compiz-core
sudo apt-get remove openbox
```

Необходимо выполнить команду

```
metacity --replace
```

но вылетает ошибка

```
Window manager error: Unable to open X display
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все нормально, я тупой
Metacity — стандартный оконный менеджер среды GNOME для UNIX-подобных операционных систем. Соответственно эти команды необходимо делать непосредственно на сервере к которому подключен норм монитор, а не по удаленке